# Is Whitney sum of vector bundle a categorical colimit?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles

We known that the direct sum of two vector spaces is the categorical colimit of vector spaces. My question is whether Whitney sum of vector bundle is a categorical colimit (in the category of vector bundles over a fixed $B$ and bundle maps fix $B$ too)? This may be too easy, just give me quick answer or reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Whitney sum is the direct sum in the category of vector bundles over $B$, where morphisms are fibrewise linear maps.